# This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, ios4

I'm testing my app on simulator 3.1.3 release, it runs fine. When it come to simulator 3.2 or 4.0, it crashes right from the beginning:

```
2010-09-28 18:36:39.957 Angeloni[23268:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'

*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0268cb99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027dc40e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02645238 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x026451aa +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x005d03fa UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2384
    5   UIKit                               0x005d1179 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398
    6   UIKit                               0x004f6d77 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 212
    7   UIKit                               0x005d04ca UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592
    8   UIKit                               0x005cfdc2 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 792
    9   UIKit                               0x005d1179 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398
    10  UIKit                               0x004f6034 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 804
    11  UIKit                               0x004f7eb5 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    12  UIKit                               0x003ad95f -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
    13  UIKit                               0x003ab675 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    14  UIKit                               0x003ab54f -[UIViewController view] + 56
    15  Angeloni                            0x000045ba -[MenuPrincipalViewController gotoOfertas:] + 109
    16  UIKit                               0x003017f8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    17  UIKit                               0x0038cde0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    18  UIKit                               0x0038f262 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    19  UIKit                               0x0038de0f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    20  UIKit                               0x003253d0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    21  UIKit                               0x00306cb4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    22  UIKit                               0x0030b9bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x02f04822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0266dff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x025ce807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x025cba93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x025cb350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x025cb271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x02f0300c GSEventRunModal + 217
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x02f030d1 GSEventRun + 115
    31  UIKit                               0x0030faf2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    32  Angeloni                            0x00002342 main + 84
    33  Angeloni                            0x000022e5 start + 53
)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Anyone ever had this problem? I read in some forum that this is a of IB problem.

If anyone can help.

Comment: Hi, Do you call instantiateWithOwner, I seem to recall this is a 4.x only method. Which makes it a bit strange that it works in the 3.1 and not above?

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out? I can't find an answer for it

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on a project where I did not use any Storyboards.

What I had to do:

- go to my project's `Info.plist` file
- remove the `Main storyboard file base name` entry there.